# I want a JQuery code that sets the focus to the previous selected input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

```html
<input type=text id="fText">
<input type=text id="sText">
<input type=text id="tText">
<input type=button id="rest">
```

When I click on fText then press the button, the cursor returns back to fText
When I click on sText then press the button, the cursor returns back to sText
and so on..

Comment: Store the input in blur event handler for inputs, and set focus to the stored element in button click handler.

Comment: Here is not a place to order the codes.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the last input element that received focus into a global variable and then, focus on it on a button click.

```js
var lastFocus;

$("input[type=text]")
  .on("focus", function () {
    lastFocus = this;
});

$("#rest")
  .click(function () {
    if (lastFocus) {
      $(lastFocus).focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id="fText">
<input type=text id="sText">
<input type=text id="tText">
<input type=button id="rest">
```

Comment: Thanks, Just I am new to programming with JQuery

Comment: Unsure why you're getting downvotes for this, it's a legitimate fix to the question posed. Just because OP 'ordered code' doesn't mean the person to post some should be downvoted. Just flag the question and move on.

Comment: @Christoph, I was going to downvote the question. It seems I downvoted you by mistake. I can't remove it unless you edit your answer. Please make some edits

Comment: Ah, it's okay. No need for a unnecessary edit :) But Amer Huriz could be so nice to mark the answer as the accepted answer.